# Hosting Firebase.json SEO-friendly URLs

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want this --> example myapp.com/myurl/

This is the custom config

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

The result is this myapp.com/myurl with this config

Answer (score 0):

There's a deployment option for trailingslash, you should set it to true.
[Firebase Hosting Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

```
"trailingSlash": true
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the 

link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.